# How can I filter my R data using conditions that have been defined in seperate .yaml file?

Tags: r, dplyr, parameters, yaml, filtering

## Situation:

So I am trying to separate out my code into two distinctive parts. The first part contains all of the parameters that could possibly change as the code is re-used again and again, and then the second part which is the bits which I expect to stay the same. Parameters go to '.yaml' file and the rest is hard coded into a '.r' file. 

Having worked with the code for a while now, it has become apparent that one part of the code that does seem to  change semi-frequently is the types of filters I need to apply to my data. For example, last month I needed only those aged over 16 included in my dataset, but now I need those aged between 8 and 55. 

What i'd like to be able to do is set some filter conditions in my '.yaml' file which can then be read in and applied to my dataset, but i'm not really sure how to do it. I've tried to mock up the situation with the titanic dataset (see below). 

So in this situation, the output I am looking for is a new dataset 'filtered_data' which only contains, males, who survived and do not have an NA in the Class column.

```
--- my_filters.yaml
filter_1:
  - "Survived == 'Yes'"  # show only people who have survived
filter_2:
  - "Sex == 'Male'" # show only those who were male
filter_3:
  - "!is.na(Class)" # show only those who do not have an 'na' in the class column
---
```

then...

```
# my_code.r

library(dplyr)
library(yaml)

# read in data
data <- Titanic

# read in filters
filters <- yaml::read_yaml("my_filters.yaml")

filtered_data <- data%>%
   dplyr::filter(filters$filter_1,
                 filters$filter_2,
                 filters$filter_3)
```

Can anyone help? I'd be very grateful for some tips/advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one problem is that you're using `Titanic` which isn't a traditional data frame, it's a table.  If we used `mtcars`, for example, we could get somewhere. Here's what the YAML might look like:

```
--- my_filters.yaml
filter_1:
  - "cyl == 4"  # show only 4 cylinder cars
filter_2:
  - "disp > 100" # show only those with displacement > 100
filter_3:
  - "!is.na(carb)" # show only those who do not have an 'na' in the carb column
---
```

Then, we could load the data and make the filters.  Below, I made some missing data in `carb`

```
library(dplyr)
library(yaml)

# read in data
data <- mtcars

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(carb = ifelse(carb == 8, NA, carb))
```

Then, we read in the filters and importantly, parse the text.

```
filters <- yaml::read_yaml("~/Downloads/my_filters.yaml")
filters <- map(filters, ~parse(text=.x))
```

Finally, we can evaluate the filters in the filter function:

```
filtered_data <- data%>%
  dplyr::filter(eval(filters$filter_1), 
                eval(filters$filter_2), 
                eval(filters$filter_3))
filtered_data
#                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710    22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Merc 240D     24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230      22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# Volvo 142E    21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Perhaps someone will post a tidier version of this, but this does the trick.

Comment: With `tidyverse`, you may use `data %>% filter(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(paste(filters, collapse = ";")))` (after directly reading with `read_yaml`